# Method(s) to output confidence score from Stanford Classifier?

Tags: java, methods, classification, stanford-nlp

I'm currently working on Stanford Classifier (version 2.1.8 released on 04-04-2013) and wrote a java wrapper for an internal research project. Based on the ClassifierDemo.java (comes with the Classifier zip file), I was able to call the my serialized trained model and property file to process one string at a time. Note that Stanford classifier can process files only, once the input string is read and then saved in a temporary file, then Classifier starts to process it. Method trainedClassifier.classOf is able to output the class for the given string using trained model (myClassifier.ser.gz). However, I can't find the method to output confidence score along with it (cf: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html).

A desire output is
stringCategory: Dummy 
Confidence Score:0.85

The following is the Java class/method that I use in the wrapper:

```
         //.....
         LinearClassifier<String, String> trainedClassifier = 
         IOUtils.readObjectFromFile("myClassifier.ser.gz");

         //Have to call *.prop every time
         ColumnDataClassifier myProp = 
           new ColumnDataClassifier("myClassifierProp.prop");

         //Specify the temporary one sentence file saved in class-tmp.txt
         for (String line : ObjectBank.getLineIterator("class-tmp.txt")) 
               { Datum<String,String> classType = myProp.makeDatumFromLine(line, 0); 
                 classOutput = trainedClassifier.classOf(classType);

                 System.out.println("stringCategory: "+ classOutput + "/n");
                  //end of for
                  //.....
```

Comment: You don't have to write a temporary file and read it with an `ObjectBank`. If you have a `String str` that contains tab-separated values for a test example, you can just go straight to: `Datum<String,String> classType = myProp.makeDatumFromLine(line);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the score using the method `Counter<L> scoresOf(Datum<L,F> example);` (Construct a counter with keys the labels of the classifier and values the score (unnormalized log probability) of each class.) which can be found in Classifier interface. You can use it like this: `trainedClassifier.scoresOf(classType)`. This will return a `Counter<String>` in this particular case. To find the score of the output class, you can use the following code:

```
score = Double.toString(trainedClassifier.scoresOf(classType).getCount(classOutput));
System.out.println("Confidence score: " + score);
```

I did on a project like I did above. You can also try this method:

```
score = trainedClassifier.scoreOf(classType, classOutput);
```

I think this will do the job too.

For more details:
[Stanford LinearClassifier Documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/LinearClassifier.html), 
[Stanford LinearClassifier Implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.2.0/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/LinearClassifier.java?av=f)